# VS Code Debug Console is blank

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm trying to run python on VSCode and as you can see in the image below, when I run the code, the output only shows up under the terminal (at the bottom of the screen). When I click 'Debug Console', there is nothing there, it is blank. How do I change the settings so that my output shows up under debug console rather than just terminal?

[image]

Comment: Click on the right drop-down inside the terminal. In drop-down delete node terminal and then see it's running their or not.

Comment: when I click the drop down inside the terminal, the only options are: '1:bash', '2:python', 'create JavaScript debug terminal' and 'select default shell'.

Comment: Check this one: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/python